# How to create a simple landing page in MVC2

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, routes

I'm trying to create a `http://domain.com/NotAuthorized` page.

went to `Views\Shared` and added a View called `NotAuthorized` witch originates the file name `NotAuthorized.aspx`

[image]

in my Routes I wrote

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "NotAuthorized", // Route name
    "NotAuthorized.aspx"  // Route Url
);
```

but every time I access `http://domain.com/NotAuthorized` I get an error

> The resource cannot be found.

**What am I missing?**

How can access this without using `View("NotAuthorized")` in the `Controller`, in other words, not passing through any controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access views directly without passing through a controller. All pages in the `Views` folder cannot be served directly. So one way to accomplish what you are looking for is to write a custom[`[Authorize]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute.aspx) attribute and set the error page:

```
protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
{
    if (!filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
    }
    else
    {
        filterContext.Result = new ViewResult { ViewName = "NotAuthorized" };
    }
}
```

Comment: I was just missing the `filterContext.Result = new ViewResult { ViewName = "NotAuthorized" };` as I already had my `RequiresRoleAttribute` in place, but I was redirecting as `filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect(notAuthorizedUrl, true);`. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 0):

I still have no idea on how to accomplish it, but what I did was use the Home `Controller` and create an Action called `NotAuthorized`

```
public ActionResult NotAuthorized()
{
    return View();
}
```

And add a route like

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "NotAuthorized", // Route name
    "NotAuthorized", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "NotAuthorized" } // Parameter defaults
);
```

And works fine now, I can easily redirect in any part of my Business Logic to `/Notauthorized` and that will route fine.